# Constant term of Laurent polynomial in many variables

Tags: polynomials, coefficients

What is the quickest way to extract the constant term from a Laurent polynomial in two variables?
For example $x+1 +x^{-2}y+x/y$ has constant term $+1$.

Comment: Actual code is vastly preferable to something that cannot be copy-and-pasted.

Answer (score 5):

```
SeriesCoefficient[x + 1 + x^(-1) y + x/y, {x, 0, 0}, {y, 0, 0}]
```

> 1

Comment: Right, is this the quickest way? assume I will repeat this operation many many times

Comment: @jj_p: at worst, it should be not too inefficient. You don't mention how complicated your Laurent series can get.